# mysql database has $ and / signs - can't get them inside of my query

Tags: php, mysql

New to databases, and need some help understanding how to retrieve items from a database - I have text items in a database with php like special symbols - and they are not coming through correctly

```
   $dealquery="SELECT * FROM deal WHERE UUID = '$UUID'";
    $dealresult=mysql_query($dealquery);
    if (!$dealresult) {    echo 'Could not run dealresult query: ' . mysql_error();    exit;}
    $dealrow = mysql_fetch_array($dealresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    var_dump($dealrow);
    $dealpromo = $dealrow['promotext'];
```

the promotext is - $15 off w/ purchase

the var_dump shows "purchase"
as does my $dealpromo

Here is some output from another database entry that is not working

code:

```
    echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                var_dump($dealrow['promotext']);echo "<br/>";
                echo $dealrow['promotext'];echo "<br/>";
                htmlentities($dealrow['promotext']);echo "<br/>";
                echo urlencode($dealrow['promotext']);echo "<br/>";
                var_dump('$10 off $20 Purchase');
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";
```

result:

string(21) " off Purchase " 
off Purchase

%2410+off+%2420+Purchase+
string(20) " off Purchase"

off Purchase

Comment: Did you try escaping strings before passing them to DB with mysql_escape_string ? BTW I would highly recommend PDO or mysqli and prepared statements for security reasons!

Comment: I would recommend dibi :) very nice and simple DB layer ;)

Comment: items are already in database
I shouldn't need a full libraries just for some simple escape syntax?

Comment: @morty346 What's exactly your problem?

Comment: I expect my variable to show "$15 off w/ purchase" but it shows "purchase"

Comment: if I use urlencode($dealpromo) I get %2410+off+%2420+Purchase

Comment: if I do echo mysql_escape_string($dealpromo); I get "off w/ purchase"

Comment: @trainoasis can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: _“if I use urlencode($dealpromo) I get %2410+off+%2420+Purchase”_ – well, so that would be `$10 off $20 Purchase` originally then. If that does not show up as such – then there must be something more going on, that you have not told us about yet. There is absolutely no reason why a simple `var_dump` should mess that up – so please look at the actual _code_ your script outputs (and not what the browser shows after interpreting it as HTML). Are you by any chance using any kind of templating engine on top of that, be it server- or client-side, that could mis-interpret the `$` sign …?

Comment: @morty346 How do you get the output of `%2410+off+%2420+Purchase` or `off w/ purchase`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($dealrow);` show exactly? It's supposed to be an array, so it should return more than just `purchase`.

Comment: I have hundreds of these sorry - the w/ seems to work with the mysql_escape_string - the dollar symbol seems to be showing up as %24

Comment: @morty346 that's urlencode(). You don't need to escape the dollar sign to insert it in a sql query.

Comment: so what do I do?? - it doesn't show up - would assume this is simple for a web developer? just looking for some quick guidance?

Comment: You shouldn't sanitize the ***output*** with `mysql_escape_string()` or `urlencode()` or similar functions. Simple `echo $dealrow['promotext'];` is enough. If this doesn't work, try `echo htmlentities($dealrow['promotext'])` instead. Also, you ***have to*** sanitize the ***input*** of your query for security reasons. To do this, add `$UUID = mysql_real_escape_string($UUID);` or `$UUID = (int) $UUID;` before the first line of your code.

Comment: _“would assume this is simple for a web developer?”_ – it is quite a simple thing in theory – and therefor with the information given so far, it is _hard_ to tell how _you managed to mess up_ a simple thing like that … so please do what you’ve been told, and answer the (implicit) questions you’ve been asked so far, f.e. what exactly you see when inspecting your data using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Or, let’s try to narrow it down a bit – put `var_dump('$10 off $20 Purchase');` in your code (exactly like this, single quote marks) – does that show up correct? (You should get `string(20) "$10 off $20 Purchase"`) If _not_, then we have at least determined that this problem has nothing whatsoever to do with your database code, but with how the output gets processed afterwards.

Comment: the UUID comes from a query above this - not from user input - so it should be secure?

as for the output - thats not working either (ill update question with all the output results

Comment: As for your updated code and the output – _if_ the value is indeed `$10 off $20 Purchase`, then the output that is to be expected from that code (and that I actually get when testing it), is not what you have shown as the output. It is `string(20) "$10 off $20 Purchase"`, `$10 off $20 Purchase` and `%2410+off+%2420+Purchase` (some of them several times, and in your code you forgot to actually output the result of `htmlspecialchars`) – so that adds weight to my suspicion, that some other kind of processing is going on _after_ you have made those outputs.

Comment: well... this is in a joomla article using jumi for php processing... but my code is quite basic - this part is within a table but nothing else going on that I know of...

Comment: And especially that the `$10`/`$20` values are _missing_ when output “raw”, but that their counterparts are still there when output via `urlencode` (`%2410` and `%2420`) suggest a high probability of some kind of templating engine looking for anything prefixed with a dollar sign and take that as a placeholder that is to be replaced by a variable value.

Comment: _“ this is in a joomla article using jumi for php processing”_ – that’s most likely to be it then. So check the docs for that extension on how a `$` is to be masked to be meant _literally_, and not as starting character of a placeholder to be replaced by that extension.

Comment: ok - deeper I go - appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after we figured out now that this has nothing to do with your actual database-related code, but with a Joomla extension that obviously has some kind of templating capabilities and therefor tries to replace placeholders of the form `$foo` with the contents of some variable, as a quick workaround you could try the following:

Replace every actual `$` dollar sign with the numeric HTML character sequence `&#36;` – that way, the extension should not recognize it as a `$` any more, but it will still be displayed as one in HTML.

```
echo str_replace('$', '&#36;', $dealrow['promotext']);
```

That *should* give you the expected output.

Comment: Looks like it is a jumi bug - http://2glux.com/forum/jumi/dollar-signs-being-stripped-form-output-t958.html